# How to create a compound index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Recently I have created a collection that contains a limited number (<5 by now) of kind of data, I created the collection with `entity_type` and `entity_id`, as following shown

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------
| entity_type | entity_id | date    | ...
+-------------+-----------+---------+------
```

And since the query for the latest records are more frequency. So I created the following compound index (note that the `entity_id` is not globally unique)

> [('date': -1), ('entity_type': 1), ('entity_id': 1)]

However, I am not sure if such index is okay since someone said that the index should not created on a field (here it is `entity_type`) which only has limited values.

Comment: Since your index includes other fields as well, which look like they will have a high cardinality (many possible values), I think this compound index will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to create mongodb index on fields which ensures high selectivity.

So if entity_type column contains limited values, I would suggest to remove this column from compound index.

[MongoDB Index Selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/#index-selectivity)

Comment: The link you given said `A better strategy, depending on your queries, would be to create a compound index that includes the low-selectivity field and another field`. So the above index is also okay even with entity_type included.